# can i use a network switch plugged into a wall outlet that is already coming from a switch?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch

in an effort to better connect my house i am setting up an in-wall wired network in my home to provide a wired option to every room.  i will be setting up a gigabit 8 port switch in the laundry room in the basement (on the west side of the house) to plug all the wall lines into, along with the main router it will allow 10 physical lines in the walls.  as it stands i have 9 lines planed for all room, including one to the living room up stairs for the TV. i intend to setup a media server somewhere on my network. my question is will it be ok to run a smaller switch (4 or 5 port) in the living room (or any room for that matter, maybe 2 devices) to split and supply the gaming devices (switch, ps5), a streaming stick (amazon fire tv) and an ethernet plug directly into the TV(smart tv streaming) off of one wall port?  rarely will more than 1 device per room be using the network at the same time, but i would like all devices to be hard wired just for the speed boosts and stability.

i am running cat 6 in the walls.  the living room is the farthest distance cable wise,  the 500ft length box i got is running out.  is it detrimental to run a switch off of a switch?  would it be better to run a 2nd or 3rd line to the living room and just supply the biggest bandwidth hogs and let the rest run wifi on an access point router fairly close?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue connecting a switch to another switch (this is called cascading).  Just be sure you do not create a loop, as this can cause errors.  As for bandwidth, each port in a switch has bandwidth dedicated to it.  By cascading a switch off of one port of another, the cascaded switch's bandwidth is limited to that of the port it is connected to.

As for running extra lines, that is entirely up to the bandwidth being used.  However, gigabit is *very* fast.  It is far faster than most home users internet speed, so they most likely not notice any slowdown on the internet.  Even internally, two bandwidth hogs probably wouldnt notice any issues.  Ultimately, it is up to you determine if it is sufficient.